# Asymptote cannot label in 3d graphs

Tags: labels, 3d, asymptote, ghostscript

I have an updated Asymptote (version 2.86) and Ghostscript (version 10.02), but cannot get Asymptote to label 3-dimensional graphs.  For example,

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
import three;
size(4cm,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);
draw(unitbox,red);
dot((7,2,0), red);
label("(1,0,0)",(1,0,0),S);
```

gives me an error

*reading array of length 0 with out-of-bounds index 0*

But if I just comment out the last line it runs fine.  I am using Windows 10.0.19045.
Could it be the settings of my Ghostscript application that are not set correctly?